# What DC comic has the Joker hugging Batman with hearts around his head?

Tags: story-identification, dc

What is the title of this DC comics book?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: with the title, I had a MUCH darker image in mind..... let's say I didn't interpret "hearts" the same way as your question does

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [The World according to the Joker](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1608874192) written by Matthew K. Manning and illustrated by Joel Gomez and Beth Sotelo.

This review explicitly mentions 'The Wheel of Dead Robins" shown in your second image:

> According to The Joker is a terrifying journey into the mind of the
>   ultimate super-villain. Featuring a wealth of bonus features,
>   including a flyer for The Joker’s first stand-up gig, a Joker gas
>   recipe, and **the outrageously interactive “Wheel of Dead Robins,”** The
>   World According to The Joker gives unparalleled insight into the
>   unhinged world of the Harlequin of Hate.